# Access User Data in Spring, Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I did this tutorial: http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-hibernate-annotation-example/

And it works perfectly. But I don't understand something. I add a new column to my database. It is named FullName. I completed the User class with the setter and getter method. But for example, how can I access this data in the admin page? How can I print out the actual session user's name. Like: Hi , your full name is .

Edit: So how can I acces the logged user's other details, like fullname, address, sex and other stuff like that, not just the username and password?

Edit2: Thanks, it is more clear now. My only question. He converts his own User class to the org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User. And this class hasn't got a contructor with fullname. So Do I need to create an own UserDetails class override the orginial. Or what have I need to do?

Edit3:  Sorry, but i don't understand this. Which service method? Can you show this for me with this example. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have add the code in the controller class `MainController` which is given in the example mentioned in the mkyong site.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView adminPage() {

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    model.addObject("title", "Spring Security + Hibernate Example");
    model.addObject("message", "This page is for ROLE_ADMIN only!");
    model.setViewName("admin");

    String fullName = ...; // Add the required logic to get the full name.
    model.addObject("FullName", fullName); // Then add the fullName to your model object

    return model;

}
```

Then finally edit the `admin.jsp` file to display the Full Name.

**Update:**

The required code is also available in mkyong link. Here is the snippet taken from the same page:

UserDaoImpl.java class has all the code that is needed for your functionality.

```
List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();

users = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
    .createQuery("from User where username=?")
    .setParameter(0, username)
    .list();

if (users.size() > 0) {
    return users.get(0);
} else {
    return null;
}
```

When you get the User object from hibernate it loads all the properties of user, as you have added new field - FullName then this field gets loaded in User object by hibernate if you have proper mapping in hbm files.

This logic is called from the service class `MyUserDetailsService` using method `loadUserByUsername`. So take help of this method from service class to get the User details by providing the `username` input parameter.

Code from service class:

```
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    com.mkyong.users.model.User user = userDao.findByUserName(username);
    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = buildUserAuthority(user.getUserRole());

    return buildUserForAuthentication(user, authorities);

}

// Converts com.mkyong.users.model.User user to
// org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User
private User buildUserForAuthentication(com.mkyong.users.model.User user, List<GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
    return new User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), user.isEnabled(), true, true, true, authorities);
}
```

As you can see here from above code, a new User object is created at line:

```
new User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), user.isEnabled(), true, true, true, authorities);
```

jut update this line to include the Full name and also add the required constructor in User class.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm interested the required logic for example.

Comment: @Roberto, have you tried understanding the example given in mkyong site? All the code is there in that example, just you need to add very few lines to add the FullName. I updated my answer with details on how you can do that.

Comment: Thanks, it is more clear now. My only question. He converts his own User class to the org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User. And this class hasn't got a contructor with fullname. So Do I need to create an own UserDetails class override the orginial. Or what have I need to do?

Comment: @Roberto, as you wanted to add an extra field, so just update the existing constructor and add the field for full name, it is not required to create one more additional class.

Comment: Ok, so maybe I am idiot. But how can I add a parameter to am existing constructor in org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User?

Comment: @Roberto, sorry I missed that the example is converting to Spring's User class. As you wanted to get the additional properties of your User entity then just call the service method and to get the User object (not the Spring class) and place it in model so the JSP page can get the user properties. Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, but i don't understand. Can you show this for me with this example. Thank you very much,